# Making maskedtextbox to read NULL from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have this short code which I use to read data into maskedtextbox and then (which isn't part of this code) UPDATE them via `SqlCommand`

```
    SqlCommand novyprikaz = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce=" + tentoradek, spojeni);
            spojeni.Open();
            SqlDataReader precti = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader();

            if (precti.Read())
            {maskedTextBox2.Text = precti.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString(); // i need to improve this part
}
```

But know if `maskedTextBox2` value is NULL it gives me an error that:

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

I would like to ask you, what should I change with this code to make it read Null?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the snippet of the code which I used to do for `INSERT INTO` It is marked as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the SqlDataReader contains a DBNull value using the [IsDBNull method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) on the column 24 and act appropriately returning an empty string or the not null value

```
 if (precti.Read())
 {

      maskedTextBox2.Text = precti.IsDBNull(24) ? 
                            string.Empty : 
                            precti.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString(); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, but it gave me this error: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: That's strange because if the Read method returns true then you have advanced the reader on the first row and this means that a record exists. Then the IsDBNull checks if the column contains no value and only if it returns false the code tries to read the column 24. Have you other code before these lines that could change the behavior expected?